# Как раскрасить градиентом линию распределения в ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Добрый день!

Клиент хочет чтобы цвет самой линии графика функции (нормальное распределение) был закрашен как градиент заданных цветов.

Я использую такой код для построения графика (ggplot):

```
p <-ggplot(f_table) +
geom_histogram( aes( value, colour = ..x..  ), binwidth = 1, fill = I("white") )+
stat_function(fun = function(x) dnorm(x, mean = mean(f_table$value), sd = sd(f_table$value)) *length(f_table$value), size = 1, colour = "gray" )+
geom_tile( aes( x=seq(1:12), y = -0.1, fill =..x.. ), height = 0.2 ) +
scale_x_continuous(
  breaks = seq(0, 10),
  expand = c(0,0),
  limits = c(0.5, 10.5)
  )+
scale_y_continuous( 
  expand = c(0.01, 0)
        )+
 scale_fill_gradientn( colours = clr )+
 scale_colour_gradientn( colours = clr )+
 theme_minimal()+
 xlab("") +
 ylab("") +
 theme ( 
   plot.margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10)
   , legend.position = "none"
   , panel.grid = element_blank()
   , axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.5, color = "grey80")
   , axis.ticks.y = element_line(size = 0.5, color = "grey80")
   , axis.ticks.length = unit (3, "mm")
)
p
```

здесь clr - это вектор:

```
  > clr
  [1] "#FF0000" "#FFC000" "#5B9BD5" "#00B050"
```

Получаю такой график
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Контуры столбиков гистограммы разукрасить получилось, но как в ggplot раскрасить градиентом саму линию графика распределения?

Должно получится, что-то вроде такого (эскиз клиента):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ggplot2` с недавних пор умеет красить линии, по сегментам.

Вот пример раскрашивания линии по значению данных.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)

library(gapminder)

gapminder %>% 
        filter(country == "France") %>% 
        ggplot(aes(year, lifeExp, color = lifeExp)) +
        geom_path(size = 1)+
        geom_point(shape = 1, size = 5)+
        scale_color_viridis()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще совсем недавно `ggplot2` так не умел. Я даже писал [issue на github](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1720)

---

В вашем случае, вероятно, стоит попробовать рассчитать данные для линии распределения за пределами `ggplot2`, а потом отобразить как обычные данные.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за наводку! Но собственно viridis не понадобился. Вынес расчет кривой, по Вашему совету отдельно и рисую ее с помощью  geom_path( data = curve, aes( x=curve$x, y=curve$value, colour = ..x..  ), size = 2,  lineend = "round" )`. В этом случае scale_colour_gradientn( colours = clr ) - раскрашивает нормально.

Comment: `viridis` -- это так, рекомендация)) В большинстве случаев эти палитры работают прекрасно

(если ответ помог, можете пометить его принятым)

Answer (score 2):

Благодаря совету выше вынес расчет кривой отдельно. В этом случае scale_colour_gradientn раскрашивает как нужно. Итоговый код:

```
curve <- data.frame(
  x <-seq(0, 10, by=0.05)
)

curve$value <-dnorm(curve$x , mean = mean(f_table$value), sd = sd(f_table$value)) *length(f_table$value)  

p <-ggplot(f_table) +
geom_histogram( aes( value, colour = ..x..  ), binwidth = 1, fill = I("white") )+
geom_path( data = curve, aes( x=curve$x, y=curve$value, colour = ..x..  ), size = 2,  lineend = "round" )+
scale_x_continuous(
  breaks = seq(0, 10),
  expand = c(0,0),
  limits = c(0.5, 10.5)
  )+
scale_y_continuous( 
  expand = c(0.01, 0)
        )+
 scale_fill_gradientn( colours = clr )+
 scale_colour_gradientn( colours = clr )+
 theme_minimal()+
 xlab("") +
 ylab("") +
 theme ( 
   plot.margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10)
   , legend.position = "none"
   , panel.grid = element_blank()
   , axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.5, color = "grey80")
   , axis.ticks.y = element_line(size = 0.5, color = "grey80")
   , axis.ticks.length = unit (3, "mm")
   , axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15, margin = margin(r=8) )
   , axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15, margin = margin(t=8) )
 )

 p
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]